# SugarCRM: Get Quotes from Opportunties

Tags: php, api, sugarcrm

I am trying to get Quotes that are related to an opportunity.
[This link](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Application_Framework/Web_Services/Examples/REST/PHP/Retrieving_Related_Records/index.html) should help me with that but it doesn't.

I shall try to explain as clear as possible what I want and what I have tried.

What I want: I make a call to our SugarCRM Instance to get Opportunities, when they have a specified status I want to achieve the Quote(s) that are related to that Opportunity.

What I have tried:

I make a call to get Opportunities:

```
$opportunities = $service->getList('Opportunities');
```

Than I use a foreach loop:

```
    foreach ($opportunities->entry_list as $opportunity)
    {
        if($opportunity->name_value_list->sales_stage->value == 'Closed Won')
            $quotes = $service->getRelatedList($opportunity->module_name, $opportunity->id, 'AOS_Quotes');

        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($quotes);
        echo '</pre>';

    }
```

The function getRelatedList looks like this:

```
public function getRelatedList($module, $id, $related_module)
{
    $get_entry_list_parameters = array(
        //session id
        'session' => $some_session,
        'module_name' => $module,
        'module_id' => $id,
        'link_field_name' => $related_module,
        'related_module_query' => '',
        'related_fields' => array(
            'id',
            'name',
        ),
        'query' => '',
        'order_by' => '',
        'offset' => 0,
        //A list of fields to include in the results.
        'select_fields' => array(
            'id',
        ),
        'deleted' => 0,
        'favorites' => false,
    );

    $entries = $this->sendRequest('get_relationships', $get_entry_list_parameters);

    return $entries;
}
```

Than this is my result for each quote:

```
object(stdClass)#5051 (2) {
  ["entry_list"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["relationship_list"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

But what does this mean? It is not what I want/expected but what should I expect and what am I doing wrong?

Can somebody please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Oke... the solution is very easy and noobish. The problem was that in trying to search for the right solution I mixed some examples up. That resulted in mixing up fields in the parameter list which caused the wrong output.